# Java: Efficient way to determine if a String meets several criteria?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I would like to find an **efficient** way  (not scanning the String 10,000 times, or creating lots of intermediary Strings for holding temporary results, or string bashing, etc.) to write a method that accepts a String and determine if it meets the following criteria:

- It is at least 2 characters in length
- The first character is uppercased
- The remaining substring after the first character contains at least 1 lowercased character

Here's my attempt so far:

```
private boolean isInProperForm(final String token) {
    if(token.length() < 2)
        return false;

    char firstChar = token.charAt(0);
    String restOfToken = token.substring(1);
    String firstCharAsString = firstChar + "";
    String firstCharStrToUpper = firstCharAsString.toUpperCase();

    // TODO: Giving up because this already seems way too complicated/inefficient.
    // Ignore the '&& true' clause - left it there as a placeholder so it wouldn't  give a compile error.
    if(firstCharStrToUpper.equals(firstCharAsString) && true)
        return true;

    // Presume false if we get here.
    return false;
}
```

But as you can see I already have 1 `char` and 3 temp strings, and something just doesn't feel right. There's got to be a better way to write this. It's important because this method is going to get called thousands and thousands of times (for each tokenized word in a text document). So it really really needs to be efficient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not try with `StringBuilder`?

Comment: If it's only going to be called thousands of times (vs. millions or billions), don't worry about efficiency until it becomes a problem.

Comment: If removing `&& true` gives a compile-time error, you've got a bigger problem...

Comment: @RohitJain: There is no need to any strings in here, actually.

Comment: Use a regex until you've measured the performance and determined it's a problem

Comment: @amit Yeah simply can be done through Regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function should cover it. Each char is examined only once and no objects are created.

```
public static boolean validate(String token) {
  if (token == null || token.length() < 2) return false;
  if (!Character.isUpperCase(token.charAt(0)) return false;
  for (int i = 1; i < token.length(); i++)
    if (Character.isLowerCase(token.charAt(i)) return true;
  return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first criteria is simply the `length` - this data is cached in the string object and is not requiring traversing the string.

You can use [`Character.isUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) to determine if the first char is upper case. No need as well to traverse the string.

The last criteria requires a single traversal on the string- and stop when you first find a lower case character.

---

P.S. An alternative for the 2+3 criteria combined is to use a [**regex**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) (not more efficient - but more elegant):

```
return token.matches("[A-Z].*[a-z].*");
```

The regex is checking if the string starts with an upper case letter, and then followed by any sequence which contains at least one lower case character.

Answer (score 1):

- It is at least 2 characters in length
- The first character is
  uppercased
- The remaining substring after the first character contains
  at least 1 lowercased character

Code:

```
private boolean isInProperForm(final String token) {
    if(token.length() < 2) return false;
    if(!Character.isUpperCase(token.charAt(0)) return false;
    for(int i = 1; i < token.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(token.charAt(i)) {
            return true; // our last criteria, so we are free 
                         // to return on a met condition
        }
    }
    return false; // didn't meet the last criteria, so we return false
}
```

If you added more criteria, you'd have to revise the last condition.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
return token.matches("[A-Z].*[a-z].*");
```

This regular expression starts with an uppercase letter and has at least one following lowercase letter and therefore meets your requirements.

Comment: Another requirement was efficiency, so I would modify it slightly to: return token.matches("[A-Z].*?[a-z].*?"); inserted question marks

Comment: Note that in regex, the caret `^` is *not* negation outside of character classes. It's a zero-width assertion denoting the start of a string.

Answer (score 0):

To find if the first character is uppercase:

```
Character.isUpperCase(token.charAt(0))
```

To check if there is at least one lowercase:

```
if(Pattern.compile("[a-z]").matcher(token).find()) {
    //At least one lowercase
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if first char is uppercase you can use:

```
Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

return token.matches("[A-Z].*[a-z].*");

Comment: There are already two answers giving the regular expression,  and they're better formatted than this.  You also need * after the .